# Problem running my project in IE 6.0 and 7.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, browser

I am using AJAX for my project. 
And the entire porject is working fine on all browsers except for internet explorer 6.0 and 7.0 too

It is working fine on IE 8.0.

Anyone has a suggestion, what i should be doing??

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a framework?  That usually solves cross browser issues.  The biggest thing is different implementations of the same features.

In this case invoking your AJAX request will have a different syntax depending on the browser.

```
//Request in standards compliant browsers:
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Request in IE 6/7
var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This [Ajax Reference (XMLHttpRequest object) - JavaScript Kit](http://www.kreeo.com/bok/XMLHttpRequest_Object/Ajax_Reference_XMLHttpRequest_object_JavaScript_Kit-qr1).